# How to avoid Spring configuring bean in Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

In a modular Spring configured application, we use factory beans to provide bean instances across module boundaries.

For example, one module **A** may expose a bean instance by the name **name**. Another module **B** can then consume that bean via a declaration of the style

```
<bean id="nameBean" class="com.zfabrik.springframework.ComponentFactoryBean">
    <property name="componentName"  value="A/name" />
    <property name="className"  value="a.AInterface" />
</bean>
```

Note that modules have separated class loader hierarchies and the actual implementation class of **A/name** may not be visible in **B**. As if in OSGI (although this is NOT OSGi).

My goal is to provide **A/name** in a programmatic application context in **B**. However when trying

```
@Configuration
public static class AppContext {
  @Bean AInterface nameBean() { 
    return lookup("A/name",AInterface.class);
  }
}
```

(lookup does the actual instance retrieval) I see that Spring is trying to configure the returned instance. For example, it will attempt to resolve @Autowired properties of **A/names**'s implementation class - which does not make sense in the context of **B** (and the deal of the lookup is to provide something fully configured anyway). Even, if I try

```
@Configuration
public static class AppContext {
  @Bean(autowire=Autowire.NO) AInterface nameBean() { 
    return lookup("A/name",AInterface.class);
  }
}
```

it will go about configuring the returned instance.

How can I provide a bean to the application context without spring touching its implementation instance?

EDIT: As suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis, returning the FactoryBean does AFAICT avoids Spring configuration of the returned instance.

The alternative code would look like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class AppContext {
  @Bean FactoryBean<AInterface> nameBean() { 
    return new ComponentFactoryBean("A/name",AInterface.class);
  }
}
```

It's not as cool as an @UntouchedBean annotation because of the FactoryBean in the return type, but it solves the problem.

@Sotirios: Please suggest as answer so that I can tag your suggestion accordingly.

/EDIT

Comment: Can you either provide a real, reproducible example or clarify what you want to happen vs what actually happens?

Comment: What do you mean by _Spring is trying to configure the returned instance_? Whatever you return from a `@Bean` method is a Spring bean and is therefore subject to Spring processing.

Comment: When providing a bean via a factory bean and declaration in the XML, Spring will not configure the returned instance. It will simply add it to the bean factory. I am looking for something similar to be used in Java configuration - albeit without factory bean.

Comment: Please show us what `lookup` does or how it's intended to be used. Does it return `ComponentFactoryBean` or the `Component`?

Comment: Lookup is actually a method of the z2-Environment runtime. Specifically it looks like this: IComponentsManager.INSTANCE.lookup(<name>,<class>). You can imagine it as a JNDI lookup. It does indeed return the actual bean instance. It is a good idea to try with a factory bean. Will do ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just so it can be closed. The suggested and accepted answer is to return the factory bean.